# qemu-system-i386.exe has stopped working (only via CLI, works fine when starting via Android Studio AVD)

Tags: android-emulator, qemu, android-virtual-device

I've browsed through many topic and answers related to the emulator crashing issue. Yet, I still have no clue how to resolve this issue.

My setup:

- Windows 10 x64 laptop - 16GB RAM - Intel Core i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.7Ghz
- Android Studio 2.3.3
- Java JDK jdk-8u141-windows-x64
- HAXM installed and activated

When I open Android Studio, I can start the emulator without any issues.
[(see picture here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saJ8R.png)
But when I try the same from the commandline, the emulator does not startup properly and stops. [(see picture here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uure8.jpg)

I've tried:

- HAXM 6.0.6 and HAMX 6.1.3
- Graphics: Software GLES 2.0 (instead of auto)
- RAM: lowered to 512 (instead of the default 1536) as mentioned in many posts
- Try a emulator with lower resulution (like Galaxy S 800x600) as also mentioned in many posts
- Use arm image to trigger arm emulator
- Add MB behind certain values in the ini file
- Set the width/height value to 0 in the ini file
- Turn off the camera (front and back) emulation
- Disable multi-core CPU (since it mentioned behind it that it's experimantal)
- I tried the emulator in the tools folder and the emulator folder

What am I doing wrong here? 
What else can I try? 
Did I forget a combination of the above mentioned items?

My end goal:
I want to make this emulator part of my CI cycle and for that I need to run a command line (or powershell) script on a Hyper-V machine (in Azure), to start this emulator, so I can hook it up to my selenium-grid (via Appium).

Comment: same problem with me, any help would be nice. I can't even start and android VM from the AVD manager

Comment: I'll look into this again once I have some test scripts running with a real device. so far no answer yet.

Comment: I've performed some tests on real devices and those work fine. I just still have this issue laying around.

Comment: In the meantime I got a replacement for my laptop (same model/OS/etc) and here the issue does not occur. It's not a solution that answers this question, but it is an indication that it is most likely a software setup, maybe a path of version that was different, but I can't investigate this anymore. Would still like to know the answer though in case it occurs again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fix it by updating my windows (windows 10) to the latest version (windows 10 version 1903 build 18362) and take the optional update (KB4512508)
in the windows update setting..
I'm using:
- Windows 10 Enterprise.
- AMD A10-4600M APU withe Radeon HD graphics.
- ram 512.
Try this solution it worked for me.